# How getIntent.hasExtra method works in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been following a tutorial from this [link](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/browse.php) which is basically about File browse concept in android. Everything works fine but I am getting confused of how passing intents between activities works in android after reading this link. The First activity is as follows,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final int REQUEST_PICK_FILE = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    filePath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.file_path);
    Browse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.browse);
    Browse.setOnClickListener(this);      
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.browse:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FilePicker.class);            
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_FILE);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        switch(requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_PICK_FILE:

            if(data.hasExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH)) {

                selectedFile = new File
                        (data.getStringExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH));
                filePath.setText(selectedFile.getPath());  
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

As far as I understood, its passing the intent "REQUEST_PICK_FILE" and based on what it returns from "FilePicker.Class" , it will perform the action because its StartActivityOnResult. Confusion starts from next activity. Here is the File Picker class,

```
  public class FilePicker extends ListActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_FILE_PATH = "file_path";
public final static String EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES = "show_hidden_files";
public final static String EXTRA_ACCEPTED_FILE_EXTENSIONS = "accepted_file_extensions";
private final static String DEFAULT_INITIAL_DIRECTORY = "/";
.......
protected String[] acceptedFileExtensions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    .........
    // Initialize the extensions array to allow any file extensions
    acceptedFileExtensions = new String[] {};

    // Get intent extras
    if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_FILE_PATH)) 
        Directory = new File(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_FILE_PATH));

    if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES)) 
        ShowHiddenFiles = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES, false);

    if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_ACCEPTED_FILE_EXTENSIONS)) {

        ArrayList<String> collection = 
                getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_ACCEPTED_FILE_EXTENSIONS);

        acceptedFileExtensions = (String[]) 
                collection.toArray(new String[collection.size()]);
    }
}
 ..............
```

Whats actually happening here? what does the lines ,

```
   if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES)) 
        ShowHiddenFiles = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES, false);
```

actually mean? We are not passing any extras like, "EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES" from previous activity and even EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES has been declared in this class. I seriously don't understand what's happening between these two activities . I am not able to proceed before understanding what's actually going on. Any help would be really great !! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does the lines... actually mean?

It means that if the `Intent` used to start `FilePicker` has an `EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES`, hold onto that value in what I assume is a `boolean` field on the activity that is not shown in your redacted code listing.

> We are not passing any extras like, "EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES" from previous activity

You could, though. You do not have to.

> even EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES has been declared in this class

That is fairly typical. `FilePicker` is declaring an API, and so it exposes the names to be used for incoming and outgoing extras. `EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES` is `public`, and so it can be referenced from anywhere, including `MainActivity`.

Comment: I am still not clear with the line "It means that if the Intent used to start FilePicker has an EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES, hold onto that value in what I assume is a boolean field on the activity that is not shown in your redacted code listing " . hasExtra will be used when we are checking if the intent that is passed from previous activity has keys specified. Wont it?  If we are not passing the intent from previous activity as you said then why the lines  if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES)) . @CommonsWare

Comment: @Anusha: "hasExtra will be used when we are checking if the intent that is passed from previous activity has keys specified. Wont it?" -- correct. "If we are not passing the intent from previous activity" -- sure you are. That is what `startActivityForResult()` does. Now, it so happens that the `Intent` that is used by `MainActivity` to start `FilePicker` does not include this extra. `FilePicker` was written to be more powerful and flexible than `MainActivity` is using. If you want to know *why* the author made `FilePicker` more powerful and flexible, ask the author.

Comment: Sorry the author is unresponsive . So I posted here and now the all the intent with hasextra() in FilePicker class won't come into being as no intents with those "keys" were passed . Is my understanding right ? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Anusha: With `MainActivity` as written, you are correct. `FilePicker` specifically uses `hasExtra()` to "gracefully degrade" in case the extras are not provided. However, a programmer could change `MainActivity` to include the extra, if desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation @CommonsWare